# uninitialized constant ActiveMerchant::Billing::Integrations::Helper (NameError) in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, activemerchant, ruby-2.3

I am try to integrate allpay payment.

```
gem 'rails', '>= 5.0.0.rc1', '< 5.1'

gem 'activemerchant', :require => 'active_merchant'

gem 'active_merchant_allpay'
```

But i am getting:

> **uninitialized constant ActiveMerchant::Billing::Integrations::Helper (NameError)**.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add offsite_payments as a dependency,and update any mentions of `ActiveSupport::Billing::Integration` to `OffsitePayments::Integrations`

https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant/issues/1357